# Binding same Eclipse key combination in multiple Team Provider contexts

Tags: eclipse, svn, mercurial, dvcs

I have a handful of Eclipse (3.5, OS X) projects using different Team version control providers. I tried to map some hot keys to the VC commands I use often, primarily "diff" with the previous revision/changeset.

Ideally I'd like to map the same key combo to work across all Team Providers where it makes sense. The key mappings of course conflict, since the commands are entirely different as far as the IDE is concerned, and Eclipse seems unaware of which Team Provider a project is using:

[image: Screen shot of Eclipse Key Mapping dialog]

Any way around this?

Comment: I reposted this question at http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/760000/ and http://eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/759765

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement your own command which would delegate to the relevant command for SVN, CVS or Mercurial, then assign you preferred keybinding to that command.
I'd check why there is not a standard API in the eclipse.team stuff for each of those commands though, there may be a good reason there is not.

Comment: Thanks... wonder if it's worth it. Might just try the Mercurial hgsubversion plugin for SVN to talk to the repository like I do with hg-git.